# How would I store different types of an object?

Tags: java, enums

I am creating a card game in Java. Each card object can have a different suit out of a selection of four and **each suit alters the way the card object functions with other objects in the game**. Otherwise, the cards behave the same way. I can assign each card object a suit by using a Boolean variable for each suit, **but doing that feels like a messy solution where things might go wrong.**

**Would using an Enum be a better solution?**

Comment: "I can assign each card object a suit by using a Boolean variable for each suit," sound like a bad idea. About "each suit alters the way the card object functions." - how does it alter exactly?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? Come back if you get stuck.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking but you might create a `enum Suit` and assign one of its members to each object.

Comment: Yes, a single `enum` field (using `enum` with 4 values) is far better than 4 `boolean` fields (exactly one of which must be true).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to make an Abstract base class that has an abstract method that each suit inherits from and implements.

```
abstract class AbstractSuit {

  public abstract int modify();
}
```

Then each suit would extend `AbstractSuit`

```
class Hearts extends AbstractSuit {

  @Override
  public int modify() {
    return 1 + 1;
  }
}

class Spades extends AbstractSuit {

  @Override
  public int modify() {
    return 2 + 2;
  }
}
```

Then you can store each of your object as `AbstractSuits` in what ever collection you want and can call `modify()`

```
List<AbstractSuit> suitList = new ArrayList<>();
suitList.add(new Hearts());
suitList.add(new Spades());

for(AbstractSuit suit : suitList) {
  System.out.println(suit.modify());
}
```

Output would be

```
2
4
```

Comment: Why not make an `enum Suit` in order to have a closed set of values, then create a separate `Map<Suit, SuitBehavior>`?

Comment: Because having an abstract base class you wouldn't have to worry about switching on enum value and trying to figure out the behavior. You can just call the classes `modify()` method and what ever suit it is would act appropriately. Also the abstract base class can handle all the functions that are similar to every suit and the abstract methods would be delegated to each suit to implement.

Comment: Map precludes the need for `switch`.

Comment: You would still have to establish that map and what would be inside SuitBehavior? I expect that would have to be a base class as well. Abstract Classes would be easier to deal with especially with what the OP said about it interacting with other classes.

Comment: Yes, a `SuitBehavior` class would be pretty much identical to your code.  The only difference is that the suit identifiers themselves are a closed set (that is, enum constants), rather than a potentially limitless set of subclasses.

Comment: Right, but that map would have to be maintained throughout the program while it would be easier to create new AbstractSuits and act on them. In my opinion the solution i presented works best for what the OP wants.